# SQL Subquery for each

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have following tables

```
create table players
(
    name varchar(30) not null primary key,
);

create table injuries

    bId int not null primarykey,
    date DATE not null,
    name varchar(30), 
    foreign key(name) references players
);

create table sportsBegins
(
    cId int not null primarykey,
    date DATE,
    sportname varchar(20),
    name varchar(30) 
    foreign key(name) references players
);
```

Following example data:

**players**

```
name
John    
Jane 
George 

shows players in db
```

**sportsBegins**

```
cId |    date   | sportname | name
1    2020-01-01   Basketball  John
2    2020-02-02   Basketball  John
3    2020-01-01   Soccer      John
4    2020-02-02   Basketball  Jane
5    2020-01-03   Basketball  George
6    2020-01-04   Badminton   George

shows what date players begin playing a sport
```

**injuries**

```
bId |    date   | name    
1    2020-01-01   John     
2    2020-02-03   Jane     
3    2020-01-05   George

shows the date these players reported injuries.
```

I want to count the number of DISTINCT players that have experienced an injury in Basketball AFTER the first day they got assigned the sport (not the same day).

So for each player, i need to only grab the first date they started playing basketball. Then for that player, i need to compate his name AND date to the name AND date in the injuries table to see if he ever reported an injury after the date he got the sport assigned.

**Example**

In the example data I provided this would be the output

```
Total basketball injuries
2
```

**Explanation of answer**

John got assigned basketball twice. Only look at first date he got assigned basketball. Then look at injuries table. He only reported an injury on that day, but never after, so ignore. Jane and George reported injuries after first day assigned basketball so count them

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the desired result

```
SELECT count(distinct injuries.name)
FROM injuries
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, min(date) as startDate FROM sportsBegins WHERE sportname = 'Basketball' GROUP BY name) as startDates ON injuries.name=startDates.name and injuries.date > startDates.startDate
```

Quick explanation:

- startDates extracts the first date each player started playing basketball
- the join condition filters only injuries which happened after the first start date for each player
- count(distinct injuries.name) ensures each player only gets counted once even if he/she reported more than one injury after the first start date

Comment: weird, I just re-checked and the SQL is syntactically correct, can you share the full error?